# Text View and Intent

Tags: java, android

So I have an activity that extends listview, and I want to create another activity that has 2 edit text fields. The second activity is opened when I click a menu item... I already did this but I don't know how to make 2 text fields in the second activity. And I was wondering if the second activity has an xml file ? and where it is or how can I change the layout of that activity. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you created 2 activities???

Comment: then wt you want in second activity?? it wud be better if you post code of your second activity.

Answer (score 2):

simply creat another xml file under the layout forlder. for example call it secondView.xml and then in the seconf Activity class change this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.secondView);
```

Comment: Yes I think so! thanks a lot ! I will try and after if I encounter problems I will post again

Comment: So it's no quite working I put setContentView in the second Activity and this activity should start when I click a menu item, but when I click that menu item the layout is not the same as the one I see in the graphical layout in eclipse

Comment: Do I have to modify something in the manifest file? To specify that the second activity's layout is the second one?

Comment: sure, you have to add your activity to the manifest something like this, just replace youractivity with the name of your own activity   <activity android:name=".yourActivity"></activity> make sure you add it next to main activity you have already there.